# what are the minimum mysql user privileges to allow optimize and repair

Tags: mysql, privileges

I need to optimize and repair all databases from a daily cron job and I don't want to use the root password so I want to create a user with the minimum privileges necessary.  I cannot find this documented anywhere.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both require `SELECT` and `INSERT`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html